# How to multiply EACH value from one row from a dataframe, with all values of a row from another datafrane

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
species = c ('A. alba', 'P. nigra', 'P.sylv', 'C. sativa', 'B. Pendula', 'Q. cerris', 'Q. petrae', 'Q. pubesc', 'P. alba', 'T. arvense')
speciesdat <- data.frame(pointID= species,matrix(runif(100),ncol=10,))

speciesdat

A. alba     0.43768279  0.70788388  0.22385977  0.4865352   0.65390645  0.6131476   0.9034217   0.9882588   0.045676450 0.1109551
P. nigra    0.23841748  0.10107243  0.31643354  0.9124586   0.17680009  0.5730999   0.3687399   0.6710573   0.424592606 0.9963007
P.sylv      0.03510202  0.66443096  0.56751081  0.2605511   0.27068835  0.3625468   0.6825015   0.6128847   0.394236153 0.9825921
C. sativa   0.83156640  0.87620244  0.28547281  0.6186353   0.03054993  0.6602586   0.7266206   0.5757858   0.044838758 0.9264902
B. Pendula  0.02853235  0.11147283  0.65968549  0.6087475   0.01859563  0.7705008   0.2588491   0.6160338   0.278875411 0.3760177
Q. cerris   0.33518206  0.66494652  0.44535126  0.6396948   0.84853701  0.8528920   0.9083867   0.3406821   0.301699912 0.7552817
Q. petrae   0.99028047  0.32606149  0.03991465  0.4070295   0.76723652  0.1510258   0.4583800   0.9209462   0.372419649 0.4774647
Q. pubesc   0.48350520  0.02714703  0.84217131  0.7785254   0.59770557  0.8242108   0.3781278   0.2444586   0.997081622 0.5707966
P. alba     0.32207762  0.17842972  0.72346310  0.2024601   0.04296549  0.7129133   0.7596528   0.1445458   0.009422524 0.9234416
T. arvense  0.46029757  0.72158301  0.35532973  0.8191271   0.85785606  0.1145541   0.7022644   0.9689575   0.524823767 0.9510237


veges = data.frame(pointID = species, matrix(runif(80), ncol=8))
veges

A. alba     0.8760049   0.08377138  0.7947616   0.15866494  0.94725913  0.4210001   0.75813441  0.03543249
P. nigra    0.5990935   0.26900508  0.6619769   0.02748618  0.06831557  0.0331052   0.74318637  0.48573950
P.sylv      0.7159880   0.84181724  0.6723000   0.52288279  0.17646907  0.7342308   0.32012234  0.12942797
C. sativa   0.1593788   0.41923564  0.6169959   0.87120304  0.51923185  0.7643932   0.15112887  0.38999869
B. Pendula  0.6589521   0.28458623  0.9378560   0.46504735  0.37802398  0.8599706   0.42625633  0.04834509
Q. cerris   0.6500326   0.33385627  0.7024338   0.11463147  0.95834461  0.9884738   0.67196514  0.47536082
Q. petrae   0.5767072   0.93077964  0.3999803   0.32463310  0.84351953  0.3218898   0.82015985  0.42689436
Q. pubesc   0.1727690   0.69179797  0.9994009   0.96287250  0.12937430  0.1530379   0.06389051  0.29790681
P. alba    0.7412723    0.74790322  0.6776089   0.92737920  0.44920139  0.9513559   0.84576046  0.22779249
T. arvense  0.6501236   0.05703468  0.2437144   0.13148191  0.40202796  0.8761405   0.53510479  0.86338306
```

The data frame `speciesdat` contains the possibility of species to exist in one cell.

What i want to do is to multiply for every species, each value of every cell from `speciesdat`, with the values from the `veges`, and create a new data frame which will contain this results.

How can i perform this calculation?

Comment: Please describe exactly what you want as a result.  It would help to make the example smaller.

Comment: As a result I want a data frame with the results from this multiplication. The new data frame will have one column with the species name and the others should have the results from the multiplication. For the data in this question should be 10 x 8 = 80 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smaller example:

```
species <- LETTERS[1:3]
speciesdat <- data.frame(pointID=species, matrix(1:9, ncol=3))
veges <- data.frame(pointID=species, matrix(10*(1:6), ncol=2))
speciesdat
##   pointID X1 X2 X3
## 1       A  1  4  7
## 2       B  2  5  8
## 3       C  3  6  9
veges
##   pointID X1 X2
## 1       A 10 40
## 2       B 20 50
## 3       C 30 60
```

`outer` can be used for this, with a bit of manipulation.  This function will take a vector, split it in two, and return the outer product:

```
f <- function(x, len) { outer(x[seq(len)], x[-seq(len)])}
```

Here are the expanded columns, retrieved by calling the above function on the merged data:

```
m <- merge(speciesdat, veges, by='pointID')
t(apply(m[-1], 1, f, ncol(speciesdat)-1))
```

Adding back in the first column with cbind:

```
x <- cbind(m[1], t(apply(m[-1], 1, f, ncol(speciesdat)-1)))
x
##   pointID  1   2   3   4   5   6
## 1       A 10  40  70  40 160 280
## 2       B 40 100 160 100 250 400
## 3       C 90 180 270 180 360 540
```

To get the names as requested in the comment, compute with `outer` again:

```
n <- c('pointID',  outer(names(speciesdat[-1]), names(veges[-1]), FUN=paste, sep='-'))
n
## [1] "pointID" "X1-X1"   "X2-X1"   "X3-X1"   "X1-X2"   "X2-X2"   "X3-X2"
```

These can be assigned the names of the structure above:

```
names(x) <- n
```

Note that the order is not as in your comment, but is correct for the operations in this example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. This is what I want. Also I would like to ask if there is a way to add a column name for example "X1 - X1", "X1 - X2", "X1 - X3", etc. just to have an idea from where you get this result.